# Is there an airport which will lose UK connection if the UK leaves the EU customs union?

Tags: airports, eu

Is there any airport without customs facilities which has a connection to the UK?

Comment: See also: *http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/86279/2509* and *http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/86274/2509*.

Comment: Question title and question body are entirely different things. Title asks about predicting the future, body asks about present situation, which can change quickly if needed. VTC for unclear.

Comment: WTF. The body is always meant to expand and clarify the title because the title is short. And no, you can't change an airport quickly to have customs if it doesn't have as you'd need to rebuild somewhat to separate the carousels from the outside. And gerrit was able to answer the question as asked -- it's definitely quite clear.

Comment: That largely depends on what deal they make but possibly yes for a while maybe until the airport is rebuilt so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I flew to [La Palma Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Palma_Airport).  They do have a corridor to check passports for arrivals from outside Schengen, but there are no gates between the luggage belts and the outside.  I did not see any customs facilities, but perhaps there exists a system to shepherd passengers and their luggage to a sealed off area that I didn't see, bypassing the luggage belts.

There exist seasonal (charter) flights from the UK to otherwise domestic airports in the northern Nordic countries, such as [Kiruna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiruna_Airport) in Sweden and [Kittilä](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kittil%C3%A4_Airport) in Finland (“Santa Claus flights”).  I suppose they must have some way of checking passports but again, at least for Kiruna Airport, I know that luggage arrives in an area that has no separation from the outside world.