# Is the ability to perform customs checks a requirement for an international airport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airports, international-travel

In flights that cross Schengen borders but remain in the EU Customs Union, passport checks are required but customs checks are not.  However, Wikipedia says that an [international airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_airport) is an airport with immigration and customs facilities.  I have made such flights that had passport checks but no customs checks.  However, are airports classified as international (by IATA and ICAO [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_airport#Standards)) still required to have the ability to do customs checks, even if they do not regularly carry out any?

This may be relevant in cases where a country [were to leave the EU Customs Union](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/86274/is-there-an-airport-which-will-lose-uk-connection-if-the-uk-leaves-the-eu-custom?noredirect=1&lq=1).

See also: *[How are occasional customs checks done at airports that do not normally have them?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/86279/2509)* and *[Is there an airport which will lose UK connection if the UK leaves the EU customs union?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/86274/2509)*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54880/discussion-on-question-by-gerrit-is-the-ability-to-perform-customs-checks-a-requ).

Answer (score 2):

**Is the ability to perform customs checks a requirement for an international airport?**

No.

As stated in the Wikipedia article referenced in the OP:

> However, as some countries have agreements that allow connecting flights without customs and immigrations, such facilities do not define an international airport.

Comment: Unfortunately, Wikipedia offers no source for that statement, and it contradicts the preceding (sourced) statement.